# Oracle SQL Missing Years Calculate Last Value and Compound Interest

Tags: sql, oracle, lag

I have the following table in Oracle:

| F1 | F2 | YEAR | AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DC1 | 123 | 2021 | 1000 |
| DC1 | 123 | 2022 | 1100 |
| DC1 | 123 | 2023 |  |
| DC1 | 123 | 2024 |  |
| DC2 | 456 | 2021 | 5000 |
| DC2 | 456 | 2022 | 6000 |
| DC2 | 456 | 2023 |  |
| DC2 | 456 | 2024 |  |

I want to calculate the missing years (`YEAR` 2023 and 2024) per grouping of `F1` and `F2` based on the `AMT` of the last available date (`YEAR` 2022) and multiply `AMT` by 2.1% compounding each year.

I've used the `LAST_VALUE` function

```
`(LAST VALUE(AMT IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY F1, F2 ORDER BY F1 F2 YEAR ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS NEXT_AMT`
```

to get the last values per grouping (1100 and 6000), but when I multiply by 2.1%, I don't get the compounding interest effect.

Desired Output:

| F1 | F2 | YEAR | AMT | NEXT_AMT | NEW_AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DC1 | 123 | 2021 | 1000 |  | 1000 |
| DC1 | 123 | 2022 | 1100 |  | 1100 |
| DC1 | 123 | 2023 |  | 1100 | 1123.1 |
| DC1 | 123 | 2024 |  | 1100 | 1146.68 |
| DC2 | 456 | 2021 | 5000 |  | 5000 |
| DC2 | 456 | 2022 | 6000 |  | 6000 |
| DC2 | 456 | 2023 |  | 6000 | 6126 |
| DC2 | 456 | 2024 |  | 6000 | 6254.65 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the ratio and then use arithmetic to do the multiplication:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             max(case when year = 2022 then amt end) over (partition by f1, f2) as year_2022,
             (max(case when year = 2022 then amt end) over (partition by f1, f2) /
              max(case when year = 2021 then amt end) over (partition by f1, f2)
             ) as ratio
      from mytable t
     )
select t.*,
       coalesce(amt,
                year_2022 * power(ratio, year - 2022)
               ) as new_amt
from t;
```

EDIT:

Oops, I misread the question.  You actually have a fixed ratio for incrementing the amount.  That is even easier:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             max(case when year = 2022 then amt end) over (partition by f1, f2) as year_2022
      from mytable t
     )
select t.*,
       coalesce(amt,
                year_2022 * power(1.021, year - 2022)
               ) as new_amt
from t;
```

I also realize that you might not want to hardcode 2022.  So:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             last_value(case when amt is not null then year end ignore nulls) over (partition by f1, f2 order by year) as last_year,
             last_value(amt ignore nulls) over (partition by f1, f2 order by amt) as last_year_amt
      from mytable t
     )
select t.*,
       coalesce(amt,
                last_year_amt * power(1.021, year - last_year)
               ) as new_amt
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b45a725b09a9a1b14c9845fde722ee9d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you! The last solution worked perfectly as I didn't have to hardcode anything.